# running site off development url using web.py and nginx

Tags: url, nginx, web.py

I'm developing a web site with web.py and nginx which, up until now I have been working on locally with the built in development server. Its now its time to move the site over to a live server. I'd like to deploy the site so the root is something like `examples.com/test` but all my url handling stuff is broken. I had thought I could create a `url_prefix` variable and pepper it around the web.py code but that sure seems dirty. It seems like the best thing to do would be to have nginx strip the prefix from the url so the web.py application never sees it but I'm not sure its even possible.

Does anybody know how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the web.py app on a local port using a web server such as [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), then configure nginx to host static files and reverse proxy the gunicorn server. Here are some configuration snippets, assuming that:

- your project is in `/var/www/example-webpy`
- your static files are in `example-webpy/static`
- your nginx configuration is in `/etc/nginx`.

#### Expose the WSGI object in your application

It looks like web.py doesn't do this by default, so you'll want something like the following in your `app.py` (or whichever file bootstraps your app):

```
# For serving using any wsgi server
wsgi_app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

More information in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667103/web-py-and-gunicorn).

#### Run your application server

Install gunicorn and start your application by running something like this (where `example` is the name of your Python module):

```
gunicorn example:wsgi_app -b localhost:3001
```

(You'll probably want to automate this using something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) so that the application server is restarted if your server bounces.)

#### Configure nginx

Put the following in `/etc/nginx/reverse-proxy.conf` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547580/1402935))

```
# Serve / from local http server.
# Just add the following to individual vhost configs:
# proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;

proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_connect_timeout 10;
proxy_read_timeout 10;
```

Then configure your domain in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name example.com
    location /test/ {
        include    /etc/nginx/reverse-proxy.conf;
        rewrite    /test/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/example-webpy/static/;
    }
}
```

Note the rewrite, which should ensure that your web.py app never sees the /test/ URL prefix. See the nginx documentation on [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) and [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

This will result in requests for `example.com/js/main.js` to map to `example-weby/static/js/main.js`, so it assumes that your web.py templates didn't add a `/static/` prefix. It also results in everything in the `static` directory becoming visible to the web, so make sure that's what you intend!

Comment: that seems to make sense to me, out of interest is there no way to do this without the need for a reverse proxy? seems like a lot of configuration for something conceptually very simple .jt

Comment: You could also try using [NgxWSGIModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxWSGIModule), which looks like an analog of [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (the normal deployment method on Apache). Personally, I prefer using a reverse proxy, because it doesn't require WSGI (Python) — you can run node.js and Ruby web apps behind the same nginx server.

Comment: In the end I decided to run the site of `subdomain.domain.com` rather than `domain.com/test` as it let me side step all my problems but this is definitely the correct answer to my original question